# Rounding Up Number to the Nearest Value on Another Table

Tags: ms-access, rounding, lookup, ms-access-2016, lookup-tables

is this something that's possible to achieve in Ms. Access?

I have two table, first table is a calculated product requirement:

[image]

Second Table is the fixed adjusted rate specific to each product (since there's a fix output rate from the equipment we used to apply the product and have to split them in a very specific rate)

[image]

The goal would be to generate this table (so I can link it to the table 2 and get a specific split rate required by the equipment)

[image]

I have been cranking my head for hours but couldn't find a solution yet. Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try below query-

```
Select t.product, MIN(t.adjusted) as Adjusted from 
    (SELECT t1.Product, t2.Adjusted
    FROM Table1 as t1 INNER JOIN Table2 as t2 ON t1.Product = t2.Product
    WHERE (t2.Adjusted>t1.calculated)) as t Group by t.Product;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this, the technique of grouping up adjusted with MIN does the trick!

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

```
SELECT Table1.*, Table2.* FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Product = Table2.Product 
WHERE Table2.Adjusted = (SELECT TOP 1 Adjusted FROM Table2 
                        INNER JOIN Table1 ON Table1.Product = Table2.Product 
                        WHERE Table1.Calculated <= Table2.Adjusted
                        ORDER BY Adjusted);
```

Comment: In case of unsorted data we may need to sort data in ascending order `SELECT TOP 1 Adjusted FROM Table2 WHERE Table1.Calculated <= Table2.Adjusted order by Product, Adjusted`.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, let me try it out on my end first.